# Setting up github as version control for my own personal projects

Tags: github

I do programming assignments for school and I would like to use Github private repositories for version control.  Right now I am trying to get it set up so that I have backups of my code as I improve it.  But also, a few students in my class are talking about doing a side project so I'd also like to be able to use github to work with them on that (but this is a second priority).  I am writing the code in Visual Studio Community 2017. I am working on Windows 10.

I created an account on Github and I downloaded some desktop software.  In the gui interface, it says version 0.21.GITGUI.  Per the advice below, I am not going to use the GUI.

Accidentally, before changing the configuration file, I went to the project folder and typed git init, then git add --all, then git commit -m "Initial commit"

Next, I set the email address and username in the config file.  I'm confused why we don't have to set the password or type a password.  Shouldn't that be needed to put the data on Github?

Next, I went back and typed all of the commands to add the folder to the repository (see 2 paragraphs back).  One error message that it gives is "On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Next, I check the github website and it doesn't seem to have the files there.  Although before I did all of this, I created a new repository there with the same name as the folder that I added using the Github command line.  I have been stumbling through a few instructions that I have found and one set of instructions seems to want to take me through a process of adding a website address to Visual studio after creating the repository on the Github website.  But, then I ended up following other instructions.

By the way, I did all of the above in Github cmd.

Here are my questions:

1. I think I have not done all of the steps in order to be able to see my code on the Github website when I log in (I don't see my code there).  What did I do wrong or where exactly can I read the code on the github website?
2. I am trying to search my computer using github bash for windows to see if there is an SSH file on my computer.  I am not sure if I can even navigate to the C drive in here.  Is that where I should conduct the search for the ssh file?

Any advice that you can give is much appreciated.  I know that this post might sound like I am not trying hard enough.  But, I have working on this for a good while, trying to follow instructions on about a dozen webpages.  I am just not as good at IT work as many of you.

Comment: Perhaps I just don't get it, but you actual question is...?
As for the password: You should add your SSH Key to your github account (`https://github.com/settings/keys`), then your local client should use this automatically (assuming you added your default ssh key). This way, no password is necessary.

Comment: thank you very much for response.  I am very grateful.  The problem is that I don't see the files in the Visual studio folder now on the github website when I log in.  Perhaps I a looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Then please edit your question to actually contain a question instead of just telling us your story and expecting us to infer any questions from that ;-) Help us help you by telling us explicitly what you want to know. As for the Github-GUI: If you are a newbie, I suggest to not use a GUI, but to use the command line tools. Thereby you remove a layer of complexity and can learn the actual tool you are using, and not just the software that uses the tool under the hood ;-)

Comment: Thanks, done.  I sometime struggle with how much detail to post vs keeping the post short enough.  I think I'll find the right balance over time.

Answer (score 0):

**About Github Private Repository**

**[GitHub](https://github.com/)** Private repositories are possible, but only with a **paid account**.

Starting at $7 per month for the Developer account, you can set up unlimited number of public and private repositories. See the [Plans page](https://github.com/pricing) for more information.

**[bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)** - Their plans seem to be the best. They give you way more than github do for free accounts - in fact, I'm still only using the free plan - no need to sign up to the paid ones; plus the interface is almost identical to Github.

And you need to add SSH keys of your machine on Github account. Check documentation here: [Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) And if you need to generate new SSH keys; check this article: [Generating a new SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) Includes instruction for MAC, Windows and Linux

**Clarification of your confusions**

**Q.** I'm confused why we don't have to set the password or type a password.

**A.** Because your machine SSH keys are already stored in Github account.

**Q.** One error message that it gives is "On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean"

**A.** try removing the origin first before adding it again. You can do this by terminal

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository_name.git
```

Hope it helps! :)